# Flipboard UI in Sencha Touch?

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, flipboard

How would I implement the two main screens of a Flipboard styled app in Sencha Touch 2?  The "table of contents" screen is a series of square tiles, while the drill down has a multi-column newspaper look.

[Update]

This new example looks helpful:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/sencha-touch-2-rc/examples/touchstyle/index.html

Comment: What did you tried so far? Show some code that does not work for you!

Comment: I'm learning Sencha Touch 2 at the moment.  For the tiles on the first screen, my first guess would be to stack a series of hbox layouts in a vbox layout.  A 3x3 tile view should look good.  As for a newspaper column layout, I'm not quite sure how to build it.

Comment: I found this on github and it looks like it would work for the tile screen: http://checkout.github.com  Not sure which version of Sencha Touch.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you need to be part of the [Flipboard Pages program](http://flipboard.com/publishers/faq/). It looks like that's currently limited to major publishers, but you could try emailing them and see how far you get.